# Getting rid of \&quot in js file

Tags: ajax, strip, quote

When i post something with " to a php page, it gets escaped with \&quot ; . To get rid of this in the php file, i've tried str_ireplace, htmlspecialchars_decode and stripslashes, nothing is working. Is there a way i can strip it out after it's returned to the js file?

Comment: post sample code, please

Comment: I post this to the php file  - <input name="images[]" id="bbc460_1441488c.jpg" value="bbc460_1441488c.jpg" type="hidden"> and goes through as this - <input name="\&quot;images[]\&quot;" id="\&quot;bbc460_1441488c.jpg\&quot;" value="\&quot;bbc460_1441488c.jpg\&quot;" type="\&quot;hidden\&quot;">

Comment: how does it return to javascript?

Comment: if you provide more specific details, you recieve the answer much faster

Comment: I post it to the php file with ajax, which is where the  '\quot' gets added for some reason. then i echo it out and it's returned to the js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you getting response from ajax request use this function to decode

```
function htmlspecialchars_decode(text)
{
   var replacements = Array("&", "<", ">", '"', "'");
   var chars = Array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "'");
   for (var i=0; i<chars.length; i++)
   {
       var re = new RegExp(chars[i], "gi");
       if(re.test(text))
       {
           text = text.replace(re, replacements[i]);
       }
   }
   return text;
}
```